# Multiple Projects in a single Rails Application for Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, web-deployment-project

I am working on an Application with Rails 3 and MongoDb which will be deployed on Heroku. The application will fetch data from several APIs on the web and then perform analytics to generate meaningful insights.

However I want to have several sub-projects in this application. For example :

Project 'P1' which performs analytics for a Company C1 and with a look and feel customized (for now different text will do with same styling) for the company. This project should be accessible on p1.domain.com

Project 'P2' which performs analytics for a Company C2 and with a look and feel (for now just different text with same styling) customized for the company. This project should be accessible on p2.domain.com

Is this possible with Heroku? How should I go about it?

Comment: I would make it one Rails app instead of sub-projects. It sounds like a typical multi-tenant app. Maybe that's the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrzej is probably right. Make it one application with routes to subdomains. Check out Ryan Bates Railscast on this topic http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3.

Heroku allows subdomains as well, check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains. This is also answered by @jpwynn @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/4872039/1792207.

T.