# How can I let my clients subdomain my Ruby On Rails / Heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, subdomain

I have an app that I want my clients to be able to subdomain.  Right now it works like this

```
www.mydomain.com/clientname/
www.mydomain.com/clientname/page1
www.mydomain.com/clientname/page2
```

How can I structure the app so that my clients can subdomain it like:

```
dashboard.client1.com        ->  www.mydomain.com/clientname/
dashboard.client1.com/page1  ->  www.mydomain.com/clientname/page1
etc
```

Can I use wildcard subdomains?

I can't figure out the terminology for what I want to do, but any references you can provide would be helpful!

Comment: Try Railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

there

I'm undergoing the same thing right now with an app in development. I came across a post and an older RailsCast by Ryan Bates:

- [Subdomains RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3): Albeit a  little older there's a lot here and I think it's worth looking through.
- "[Rails, Heroku and Subdomains. Is my special case scenario feasible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871035/rails-heroku-and-subdomains-is-my-special-case-scenario-feasible?rq=1)" on StackOverflow. I'm using Heroku in particular so I'm going to see how this pans out.

And if you've found anything of note PLEASE let me know.

Thanks.