# Subdomains working locally in Rails 4, but not in production (using Heroku and Godaddy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

My rails app uses subdomains to handle requests from different user roles. The app has two user roles, Role1 and Role2. I've been using vcap.me:3000 to test this locally.
For example: the request "role1.vcap.me:3000" is processed differently than "role2.vcap.me:3000" because I want Role1 users to see a page that's different to that of Role2 users.
The above mentioned works perfectly locally.

My problem is that in production, this is not working:
I purchased a domain from GoDaddy (example: domain.com) and I'm deploying to Heroku (example: myapp.herokuapp.com)

I was able to point www.domain.com to myapp.herokuapp.com in GoDaddy by adding a CNAME record that points 'www' to myapp.herokuapp.com. So if I send a request to www.domain.com, I'm directed to my app. However, I have not been able to make the subdomains work. Example: this request role1.domain.com does not direct me to my app.

I followed [Heroku's docs on Custom Domain Names for Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-wildcard-domain) and I tried to find answers in stackoverflow and other sites (links below) that would help me figure out my problem but I couldn't get any of their solutions to work.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086225/heroku-godaddy-ssl-wildcard-setup

[Rails, Heroku and Subdomains. Is my special case scenario feasible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871035/rails-heroku-and-subdomains-is-my-special-case-scenario-feasible)

https://forum.upcase.com/t/subdomain-not-working-in-heroku-and-namecheap/5096

Some posts are suggesting that I need to use something like DNSimple (which I never used before). 
Do I need to use a service like DNSimple? How should I set things up in that case?
Or, can I set things up properly just with GoDaddy? What should I do in that case?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated since I have little experience with DNS.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What Heroku tier are you on? I'm not entirely sure, but if you're using the free tier, I don't think subdomains are supported.

Comment: I'm on the free tier, but I plan to upgrade once I get the app up and running. Could you refer me to the source of your information? Thanks

Comment: Search through SO for keywords "rails subdomain heroku." I seem to recall reading an answer indicating that the creation of subdomains for free tier apps was "no longer possible on heroku" or words to that effect, but I couldn't find the QA just now.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem! 
I didn't have to use a service like DNSimple and could make it work just through GoDaddy.
I added a CNAME record *.domain.com that points to myapp.herokuapp.com and added the domain *.domain.com in heroku by doing: heroku domains:add *.domain.com